# problema con ciclo switch

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa que ingrese 6 calificaciones y este programa lo lleve a cabo con algunos ciclos, en este caso el problema de donde viene creo que es del switch, veran tengo un menu con 3 casos, el caso 1 es capturar datos, el caso 2 es mostrar datos y el caso 3 es salir. y lo que quiero hacer es que cuando vaya al caso 2 sin antes haber pasado por el caso 1 me diga que "no se ha capturado datos".. estoy usando una bandera(ban) para cuando termine el caso 1 se active la bandera y me permita pasar al caso 2.. pero si voy al caso 2 sin haber pasado por el caso 1 el ciclo se empieza a repetir y a repetir. por lo que solo quiero que me diga "no se ha capturado datos" cuando vaya al caso 2 directamente.

```java
int op;
double n = 0;
double suma = 0;
int Ban = 0;
int w;
double promedio=0;
do {
    op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1.Capturar \n2.Mostrar \n3.Salir"));
    switch (op) {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                w=0;
                do {
                    n = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su calificacion: " + i));
                    if(n>=6 && n<=10) {
                        suma = suma + n;
                        w=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Numero "+n+" fuera de rango, volver a capturar");
                    }
                } while(w==0);
            }
            promedio = suma / 6;
            Ban = 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            if (Ban == 1) {
                if (promedio >= 9.6 && promedio <= 10) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Sobresaliente: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
                } else if (promedio >= 9 && promedio <= 9.5) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Avanzado: " +String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
                } else if (promedio >= 8 && promedio <= 8.9) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Intermedio: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
                } else if (promedio >= 7 && promedio <= 7.9) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Basico: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
                } else if (promedio< 7) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente no aprobado: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha capturado datos");
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo del programa");
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de opcion");
            break;

    }

} while (op != 3);
```

Comment: Tienes el `else` mal ubicado. Se lo pusiste a `if` de adentro y va con el de afuera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes el `else` de cuando no tienes datos, en el lugar erróneo. Tienes que ponerlo así, con el `else` fuera de la cadena `else-if` de arriba:

```java
if (Ban == 1) {
    if (promedio >= 9.6 && promedio <= 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Sobresaliente: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
    } else if (promedio >= 9 && promedio <= 9.5) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Avanzado: " +String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
    } else if (promedio >= 8 && promedio <= 8.9) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Intermedio: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
    } else if (promedio >= 7 && promedio <= 7.9) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente Basico: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
    } else if (promedio< 7) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Competente no aprobado: "+String.format("%.1f",  promedio));
    }
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha capturado datos");
}
```

Comment: Ya veo como no me pude dar cuenta de eso, Muchas Gracias